# Get plots from CombinedDomainXYPlot (and remove them)

Tags: java, jfreechart

**Is there a way to get plot list added to CombinedDomainXYPlot** if I don't keep any references to them?

I'd like to get there plots, work with them and possibly remove them from the compined plot.

This is example code for adding plots to CombinedDomainXYPlot:

```
// axis
DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");

// plot container
CombinedDomainXYPlot plotCombined = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(domainAxis);

// plot 1
XYPlot plot1 = new XYPlot();
plot1.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
plotCombined.add(plot1);

// plot 2
XYPlot plot2 = new XYPlot();
plot2.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
plotCombined.add(plot2);
```

**Update 1:**

I've just tried this code but it doesn't return all the plots. It's not reliable.

```
for (Object sp : plotCombined.getSubplots()) {
    plotCombined.remove((XYPlot)sp);
}
```

It this method of removing the plots correct?

Full example code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;


public class sample27 extends JFrame {

    public sample27()  {
        super("sample27");

        // axis
        DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");

        // plot container
        CombinedDomainXYPlot plotCombined = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(domainAxis);

        // plot 1
        XYPlot plot1 = new XYPlot();
        plot1.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        plotCombined.add(plot1);

        // plot 2
        XYPlot plot2 = new XYPlot();
        plot2.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        plotCombined.add(plot2);

        System.out.println("plot count before: " + plotCombined.getSubplots().size());
        for (Object sp : plotCombined.getSubplots()) {
            System.out.println("removing subplot: " + sp);
            plotCombined.remove((XYPlot)sp);
        }
        System.out.println("plot count after: " + plotCombined.getSubplots().size());       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new sample27();
    }   

}
```

Output:

```
plot count before: 2
removing subplot: org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot@15615099
plot count after: 1
```

Comment: `It's not reliable.` Can you post an example showing this to be unreliable? The `getSubplots` returns a copy of the underlying List, but that list should contain all items added to (and not removed) before the call

Comment: @copeg Of course, I updated my question. I assume I do something bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSubplots` returns a `List` containing all the items - this `List` is *copy* from the standpoint that it uses `Collections.unmodifiableList`, which returns a new `List` backed by the original. As you iterate over the `List`, items are in fact being removed from the underlying `List`, affecting the iteration over the `Collection`.

Rather than rely on iteration (eg `for (Object sp : plotCombined.getSubplots())`), loop over the array backwards and use the index to remove the item.

```
for ( int i = plotCombined.getSubplots().size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
    plotCombined.remove((XYPlot)plotCombined.getSubplots().get(i));
}
```

Comment: It looks working, thanks. I suggest to change the loop to this:
  for ( int i = plotCombined.getSubplots().size()-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
 plotCombined.remove((XYPlot)plotCombined.getSubplots().get(i));
  }

Comment: I mean to add `size()-1` and type change to `(XYPlot)`.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the typos.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650325/230513), iterate over a modifiable list constructed from the unmodifiable list returned by [`getSubplots()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html#line.364).

Code:

```
List<XYPlot> list = new ArrayList<>(plotCombined.getSubplots());
for (XYPlot plot : list) {
    plotCombined.remove(plot);
}
```

Console:

```
plot count before: 2
plot count after: 0
```